# I have modified the server on Jenkins, but I still prompt for the error in the screenshot

Tags: jenkins

I have modified the server on Jenkins, but I still prompt for the error in the screenshot

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text - it helps no one and does not get you help. Paste text as text and mark it as " {} " a text block

Comment: Also, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: please post the error as text so people do not need to download pictures

Comment: Changed the image syntax but please remove and post error in a code block instead